# including .Rmd file in Shiny dashboard

Tags: r, knitr, shinydashboard

I am trying  to embed an `.Rmd` file in my Shiny dashboard using:

```
HTML(markdown::markdownToHTML(knitr::knit('server.Rmd', quiet = FALSE)))
```

When I run the app, the width of the web page shrinks as shown below. How do I control the page size?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I too had this issue, I have added the below code in ui.R and it helped me to render properly:

```
tags$head(tags$style(HTML("
                           body {
                            width: 100% !important;
                            max-width: 100% !important;
                            }

                            ")))
```

hope this helps

Comment: does this help?

Comment: I used `tags$iframe(src = 'server.html', width = '100%', height = '1000px',frameborder = 0, scrolling = 'auto')` to adjust the width. I have not tried the way you suggested. I will let you know when I do so. Thanks.